# How to generate code in java file rather than in aspectJ file when creating and advanced roo addon?

Tags: aspectj, spring-roo, add-on

I am in the process of creating an advanced Roo add-on. Besides the fact that there is almost no existing documentation, and I'm hitting on multiple issues, the one that gives me now headaches is the following:

I need to modify a method from a controller. That method already exists in the respective generated Roo controller .aj file. However, if I create a new method in my .aj file, having the same name, I get an error. On the Roo forums they say that this kind of code should be injected directly in the .java file. Ok, I agree with that, but anybody knows how?

Kind regards,
Radu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution.
One needs to get the path to the java file to write to by using ProjectOperations, then using MutableFile in order to be able to operate the file.